I, D Standalone Control
I have experience applying P, PI, and PID control to the transfer function of a second-order DC motor or first-order DC motor, ignoring inductance effects.
This time, I plan to experiment with applying I controller and D controller separately.
I believe that by adjusting the coefficients, the output will converge.
Is my experiment reasonable?

an I controller can be useful occasionally. D alone is unlikely to be useful; remember that the differential operator amplifies noise.

@Hearth Thank you. Could there be any errors in the configuration during the process?

It's a basic question, just for confirmation.

@noncookie In general, I would consider using a D term with no P or I term to be an error in the configuration.

A bare "D controller" doesn't make sense!
Here's why...
In general, the output signal of a PID controller is the sum of P, I, and D term:
$$ u(t) = K_\text{p} e(t) + K_\text{i} \int e(\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau + K_\text{d} \frac{\mathrm{d}e(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} \hspace{3em} \text{(I)}$$
where e(t) is the current error (difference between set and act value):
$$e(t)= set(t) - act(t) \hspace{5em}\text{(II)}$$
Based on (II) the D-term in equation (I) can be rewritten in discrete form like this:
$$K_\text{d} \frac{\mathrm{d}e(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = K_\text{d} \frac{e(t_2) - e(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} = K_\text{d} \frac{set(t_2)-act(t_2) - set(t_1)+act(t_1)}{t_2 - t_1}$$
In a real controller the set value can generally be considered to be time-constant (the set value may change in a short term, but that's not relevant here), so
$$set(t_2) = set(t_1)$$
This means, that
$$K_\text{d} \frac{set(t_2)-act(t_2) - set(t_1)+act(t_1)}{t_2 - t_1} = $$
$$K_\text{d} \frac{set(t_1)-act(t_2) - set(t_1)+act(t_1)}{t_2 - t_1} = $$
$$K_\text{d} \frac{act(t_1) - act(t_2)}{t_2 - t_1} \hspace{5em}\text{(III)}$$
This expression (III) for the D term is completely independent of the set value and therefore contradicts the definition of a closed-loop controller.
Or in other words: The difference between the last and the current error is just the same as the difference between the last and the current value.
The D term is just an improvement for P or PI controllers to handle fast changes, limit slew rate, etc) but is not relevant in a standalone application.
